# make run for RISC-V Rocket chip emulator fails

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip, verilator

I'm following the README here to get set up: https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip. When I run `make -j6 run` in my `$ROCKETCHIP/emulator` directory, I get the following error message:

```
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-fclass.out] Error 255
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-fcmp.out] Error 255
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-move.out] Error 255
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-ldst.out] Error 255
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-fcvt.out] Error 255
make: *** [output/rv64uf-p-fcvt_w.out] Error 255
```

I opened up one of the *.out files and it outputted:

```
using random seed 1586636887
This emulator compiled with JTAG Remote Bitbang client. To enable, use +jtag_rbb_enable=1.
Listening on port 37902
emulator-freechips.rocketchip.system-freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig: ../fesvr/dtm.cc:61: uint32_t dtm_t::do_command(dtm_t::req): Assertion `resp_buf.resp == 0' failed.
```

I updated rocket-tools and rebuilt it but still got the same errors.  I'm able to skip to generating synthesizable Verilog in the `vsim` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not dig into this, but it seems that this is a bug recently introduced to the `master` branch of `rocket-chip`. Switching to a tagged version (`v1.2.4` is the latest stable) can solve this problem.

```sh
cd rocket-chip
git checkout v1.2.4
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd emulator
make -jN run
```